# How to show index.htm correctly like original index.html in Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, windows-server-2016

I am using Windows Server 2016, Apache httpd 2.4. I need upload static web content, start point is `index.htm` , not `index.html` .

host file

```
127.0.0.1 help.numbooks.com
```

My error

[image]

It show directory listing, not render htm file correctly.

My entry-point file http://help.numbooks.com/index.htm

But use http://help.numbooks.com it show listing of directories, it was not expected.

My try

[image]

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName help.numbooks.com
  DocumentRoot "C:\vy\Frameless"
  DirectoryIndex index.htm
 
  <Directory "C:\vy\Frameless">
      AllowOverride All
  </Directory> 
    ErrorLog "C:\help.log"
    CustomLog "C:\help_custom.log" common  
</VirtualHost>
```

(Of course, I restart Apache services after change configuration). How to show index.htm correctly like original index.html in Apache 2.4?

Comment: Might be a good idea to stop exposing your RDP to the Internet...

Answer (score 1):

In `httpd.conf`, change

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.htm
</IfModule>
```